# Problems with SerialPort class in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, usb, serial-port

I'm trying to diagnose why some USB serial port adapters do not work well with [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework). The behavior of the affected adapters is after `SerialPort.Write()`. Calling any of
the `SerialPort.Readxxx()` methods causes the method to block until about `ReadTimout`.
The workaround that I have discovered is to use a loop to block while `BytesToRead` is
`<= 0`, and then everything works as expected. Why?

I have collected [some debug logs](http://www.mediafire.com/?iyppr15f4btk1j0) using [Sysinternals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winternals)' [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx). Why is this happening?

```
without.log = bad behavior/bad USB adapter
with.log = with the while loop/bad USB adapter
ftdi.log = good behavior/good USB adapter
```

I wrote two native implementations of ReadByte() and can now better characterize the issue.
With ReadIntervalTimeout and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier set to MAXDWORD ReadFile(), it is 
supposed to wait until a byte is in the receive buffer and return as described on MSDN's
COMMTIMEOUTS structure page.

The Portmon logs show that this is how ReadByte() is setting up the serial port. But if
the receive buffer is empty when ReadFile() is called ReadFile() it waits until ReadTotalTimeoutConstant and then returns.
Microsoft's ReadByte() also sets up a Comm event; the Portmon logs clearly shows the event is firing, but ReadByte() never reads the receive buffer. I implemented this in my native version of ReadByte() and it works perfectly with the affected USB-to-serial adapter.

[Native ReadByte()](http://www.mediafire.com/?zkktn02pe12fk3t)

Answer (score 1):

The best idea to read SerialPort is using async-ous method:

```
_port = new SerialPort();
_port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnComPortDataReceived);

void OnComPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   byte[] ba = new byte[_port.BytesToRead];
   total = _port.Read(ba, 0, _port.BytesToRead);
}
```

Comment: the DataReceivedEvent isn't guaranteed to fire, and in my testing 40% of the events never reach the app

Comment: Could you explain why "DataReceivedEvent isn't guaranteed to fire"?

Comment: The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received. Use the BytesToRead property to determine how much data is left to be read in the buffer                           http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not guaranteed to fire eventually. It's just not guaranteed to fire for every byte received so you might get more than one byte per firing of the event.

Comment: Rather strange problem. Maybe your adapter is not working good. I've checked with my old GSM phone (connected to USB as modem), tried to send some AT commands and everything is ok. I've checked it with portmon also... Could you post your code here?

Comment: this is just a test app to demonstrate the problem and a workaround, only affects some USB to Serial adapters I tried to get the data received event to work but it turned into a huge mess that always resulted in a while BytesToRead <= 0 to make it reliable  http://www.mediafire.com/?ub0n2ke3022dvb0

Comment: I think, that you are C/C++ programmer :) When I came to C# I worked with serial the same way. But you should switch to events, really! I suggest you to log every byte in DataReceivedEvent handler and to check whether all data came

Comment: This code is used to move a telescope, I have had two uncontrolled slews trying to use events, not reliable enough for my use. I had an DataRecievedEvent handler that all it did was incriment a counter and found that up to 40% of the events got lost. weather or not I should be using events is not the question.